# How to check if a URL is an image or Youtube video

Tags: android, image, youtube

I have created this method which firsts checks if a URL is valid, and then checks if it links to an image or if it is a youtube video. My program fails when it gets to the

```
String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
```

portion of the method. Why is this happening?

Also, is it extraneous to check if its a valid URL using URLUtil.isValidUrl() as well as creating a connection and attempting to open that connection.

```
private boolean checkContent() {
    //check if valid image
    boolean img = false;
    boolean youtube = false;
    if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageAddress)) {
        URLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = new URL(imageAddress).openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
        img = contentType.startsWith("image/");

        if(!img) {
            // Check host of url if youtube exists
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageAddress);
            if ("www.youtube.com".equals(uri.getHost()))
                youtube = true;
        }
    }
    return img || youtube;
}
```

I have internet permissions in my Manifest!!!

```
Process: com.example.robert.demo, PID: 11504
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
            at com.example.robert.demo.Demo.checkContent(Demo.java:110)
            at com.example.robert.demo.Demo.submitFile(Demo.java:89)
            at com.example.robert.demo.Demo.submitClick(Demo.java:65)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: I added the log above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418) at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)

Try running the web method code on a separate thread, like this:

```
if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageAddress)) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = new URL(imageAddress).openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
            img = contentType.startsWith("image/");

            if(!img) {
                // Check host of url if youtube exists
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageAddress);
                if ("www.youtube.com".equals(uri.getHost()))
                    youtube = true;
                }
            }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Where should the variables youtube and img be declared? Outside or inside of the new thread?

Comment: Good question. Based on your code, you'd need to declare the variables inside the thread since it will be accessed from within the inner class. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I went this route.

Comment: I have a follow up question though: this method is part of a larger method that is activated by a button click on my application. To trigger your suggested method, i click my applications button. To progress farther through the parent method, I have to click a second time. How can I make it so that one click on my application sets off the thread above as well as finishes the method it is imbedded in?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I believe the way you can accomplish this is by splitting the large method into two parts and then calling the second part once the first completes.

So you press the button and the first part of the method begins including the thread. At the end of the thread, call the second part of what was your large method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map<String, List<String>>` for getting header fiels. Try this:

```
 private boolean checkContent() {
        //check if valid image
        boolean img = false;
        boolean youtube = false;
        if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageAddress)) {
            URLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = new URL(imageAddress).openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
    //This area shows keys and values for headerfields in logcat.
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Log.d("Keysss", "Key : " + entry.getKey() + 
                 " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }

    //get header by 'key'
    String contentType= connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");

            img = contentType.startsWith("image/");

            if(!img) {
                // Check host of url if youtube exists
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageAddress);
                if ("www.youtube.com".equals(uri.getHost()))
                    youtube = true;
            }
        }
        return img || youtube;
    }
```

Comment: Assuming that conn.getHeaderFields() is connection.getHeaderFields(), this method fails when the map is created. Something with .getHeaderFields() does it. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you add your log??

Comment: Identical to the one above. It throws the same main three exceptions as above

Comment: sorry i missed it. Your class must be in AsyncTask. Put your code inside asynctask. Then your code will be fine ;)